# Root node size to take sum of children nodes size when collapsed

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am exploring this [force layout example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288).

I want to pass the sum of children nodes size to the parent node when it is collapsed.

e.g, when `cluster` node is collapsed, it should take the size equal to the sum of children nodes. i.e. `3938+3812`

```
{
 "name": "cluster",
 "children": [
  {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
  {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
 ]
}
```

I have come up with some code but not sure how to wire it properly :

```
function getSize(node){
  return node.size;
}

function calcsize(node){
  var rootSize=0;
  if (node.children) rootSize= rootSize+node.children.forEach(getSize);
 return rootSize;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version of [Mike's collapsible force layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288) in which collapsed nodes get the size of the sum of their children (recursively):

```js
var data = {
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "analytics",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "cluster",
          "children": [
            {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
            {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
            {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
            {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "graph",
          "children": [
            {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
            {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
            {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
            {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
            {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "optimization",
          "children": [
            {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "animate",
      "children": [
        {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
        {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
        {
          "name": "interpolate",
          "children": [
            {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
            {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
            {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
            {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
            {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
            {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
            {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
            {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
            {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
          ]
        },
        {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
        {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
        {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
        {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
        {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
        {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
        {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
        {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
        {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "converters",
          "children": [
            {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
            {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
            {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
            {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
            {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
          ]
        },
        {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
        {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
        {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
        {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
        {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
        {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "display",
      "children": [
        {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
        {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
        {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
        {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "flex",
      "children": [
        {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "physics",
      "children": [
        {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
        {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
        {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
        {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
        {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
        {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
        {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
        {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "query",
      "children": [
        {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
        {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
        {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
        {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
        {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
        {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
        {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
        {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
        {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
        {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
        {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
        {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
        {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
        {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
        {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
        {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
        {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
        {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
        {
          "name": "methods",
          "children": [
            {"name": "add", "size": 593},
            {"name": "and", "size": 330},
            {"name": "average", "size": 287},
            {"name": "count", "size": 277},
            {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
            {"name": "div", "size": 595},
            {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
            {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
            {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
            {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
            {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
            {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
            {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
            {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
            {"name": "max", "size": 283},
            {"name": "min", "size": 283},
            {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
            {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
            {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
            {"name": "not", "size": 386},
            {"name": "or", "size": 323},
            {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
            {"name": "range", "size": 772},
            {"name": "select", "size": 296},
            {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
            {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
            {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
            {"name": "update", "size": 307},
            {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
            {"name": "where", "size": 299},
            {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
            {"name": "_", "size": 264}
          ]
        },
        {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
        {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
        {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
        {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
        {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
        {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
        {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
        {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
        {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
        {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "scale",
      "children": [
        {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
        {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
        {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
        {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
        {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
        {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
        {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
        {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
        {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
        {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "util",
      "children": [
        {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
        {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
        {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
        {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
        {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
        {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
        {
          "name": "heap",
          "children": [
            {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
            {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
          ]
        },
        {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
        {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
        {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
        {
          "name": "math",
          "children": [
            {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
            {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
            {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
          ]
        },
        {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
        {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
        {
          "name": "palette",
          "children": [
            {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
            {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
            {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
            {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
          ]
        },
        {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
        {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
        {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
        {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
        {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "vis",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "axis",
          "children": [
            {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
            {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
            {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
            {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
            {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "controls",
          "children": [
            {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
            {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
            {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
            {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
            {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
            {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
            {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
            {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
            {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
            {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
            {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "data",
          "children": [
            {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
            {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
            {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
            {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
            {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
            {
              "name": "render",
              "children": [
                {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
                {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
                {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
                {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
              ]
            },
            {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
            {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
            {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "events",
          "children": [
            {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
            {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
            {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
            {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "legend",
          "children": [
            {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
            {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
            {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "operator",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "distortion",
              "children": [
                {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
                {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
                {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "encoder",
              "children": [
                {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
                {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
                {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
                {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
                {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "filter",
              "children": [
                {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
                {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
                {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
              ]
            },
            {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
            {
              "name": "label",
              "children": [
                {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
                {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
                {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "layout",
              "children": [
                {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
                {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
                {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
                {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
                {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
                {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
                {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
                {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
                {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
                {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
                {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
                {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
                {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
                {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
                {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
              ]
            },
            {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
            {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
            {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
            {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
            {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
          ]
        },
        {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var width = 960,
  height = 500,
  root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

root = data;
update();

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Update the nodes…
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; }).style("fill", color);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
    .style("fill", color)
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);
}

Array.prototype.sum = function() { return [].reduce.call(this, (a, i) => a + i, 0); };

function rescursiveSum(node) {
  if (node._children) return node._children.map(subnode => rescursiveSum(subnode)).sum();
  if (node.children) return node.children.map(subnode => rescursiveSum(subnode)).sum();
  return node.size;
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

  node.attr("r", n => {
    if (n._children) return Math.sqrt(rescursiveSum(n)) / 10;
    if (n.children) return 4.5;
    return Math.sqrt(n.size) / 10;
  });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update();
  }
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

---

The sizing of nodes happens within the `tick` function in which the `r` attribute (radius) of circles is determined based on the `size` attribute of leafs. And for non-leaf nodes, the default size has been set to 4.5px.

Leafs data structure contains this `size` attribute, which is used to determine the radius of circles. Non-leaf nodes have either a `_children` attribute or a `children` attribute which is in both case a list of leafs containing the `size` attribute. It's `_children` or `children` depending on whether the node is collapsed or not.

The idea is thus to recursively compute the sum of children's leafs sizes.

Here is the modified part of the `tick` function handling circles sizes:

```
node.attr("r", n => {
  // Non-leaf collapsed nodes:
  if (n._children) return Math.sqrt(rescursiveSum(n)) / 10;
  // Non-leaf non-collapsed nodes:
  if (n.children) return 4.5;
  // Leafs:
  return Math.sqrt(n.size) / 10;
});
```

And here is the recursive computation of the sum of leafs sizes:

```
  Array.prototype.sum = function() { return [].reduce.call(this, (a, i) => a + i, 0); };

function rescursiveSum(node) {
  if (node._children) return node._children.map(subnode => rescursiveSum(subnode)).sum();
  if (node.children) return node.children.map(subnode => rescursiveSum(subnode)).sum();
  return node.size;
}
```